# Why is it that traits for operator overloading require ownership of self?

Tags: memory-management, rust, borrowing

Why can't I just use `&self` in the `Add` trait:

```
pub trait Add<RHS = Self> {
    type Output;
    fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output;
}
```

That way I don't have to worry about my struct moving after I use the `+` operator. It's generally not a problem for me cause I use `#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]` but still I wonder why.